# How to make a round fence out of an array

Tags: modeling

I am modelling a big fan and uses this image as a reference.

[image: Big fan]

If you look closely you see a fence/mesh/gauze before the blades. I cannot figuring out how to do this easily. Any thoughts?

[image: Model of a industrial fan]

Comment: I've tried to use Proportional Editing but cannot figure out the right Fall Off. Image: https://ibb.co/d9dBfe

Comment: I would use a boolean modifier with a cylinder. Create a cylinder that is the same diameter you want the mesh to be and add the boolean modifier to the mesh. Try setting the boolean modifier to intersection mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Plane and subdivide 20 cuts

Add a Circle and go in edit mode and Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to fill the faces

Now go to top ortho view

Select the circle and then plane with shift select

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> now

Press <kbd>Space bar</kbd> and type Knife projection

When it cut the circle Press <kbd>P</kbd> and select selection

Now the cut circle is separated. Delete the circle and plane and keep the new cut circle.

In edit mode Press Delete -> select only faces.

[image]

Convert the cage now to curve

Add a curve circle and bevel it to give thickness to the edges.

Comment: Could you elaborate the last part about converting to curves?

Comment: or don't delete the faces, don't convert to curve, and use the Wireframe modifier